# BFS and DFS in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to test BFS and DFS algorithms on my Neo4j graph.
[In this article](https://neo4j.com/blog/graph-algorithms-neo4j-15-different-graph-algorithms-and-what-they-do/) there is a list of Algorithms including BFS and DFS, but no links to a plugin Github repository. Where I can find documentation about them?

Answer (score 0):

The [neo4j-graph-algorithms](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms) git repo contains the main neo4j graph algorithm plugin, and you can get the latest release [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/releases). [Complete documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/) is also available.

The APOC library also has [Expand Paths](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) procedures that can accept a `bfs` boolean.

Comment: i saw the neo4j-graph-algorithms and it's documentation . there is no mentionning of BFS or DFS ,only a description of the shortest path algorithm telling that it uses BFS usually but not always

Comment: There is not much documentation about exactly which neo4j graph algorithm uses BFS versus DFS. You will have to fig into the code, at [neo4j-graph-algorithms](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms), get a full picture. The [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) code is also open source.